# Cannot login to my db

Tags: oracle, exception, authentication, oracle11g

I want to login to my db but an exception occur which appears in the image bellow
If there's no way to login how can  I restore the data??

[image]

**EDIT**: check the configuration of my user
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is configured in `tnsnames.ora.`
Check if the server IP is properly entered and the port is also 1521
Check if oracle is configured as a service or SID.
instead of localhost use machine name or IP

Comment: just check the configuration of my user <enter image description here> can you provide some info ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your l[istener.ora](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm) file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a lsnrctl status to see what port the listener is running on and what services/sids are registered . I believe you are trying to run the db on your workstation. you might want to check the services.